# MBP Retina end 2014 is freezing before or during entering password

Tags: macos, startup, hardware

MacBook Pro Retina (mid 2014) is freezing once user log-in interface has been loaded. Thus, password cannot be entered. Usually, freezing starts before password can be entered or while entering the first digits of the password.
Laptop is working just fine while being loaded in safe mode. Following has been done so far:

- Reinstall fresh OS (Catalina, Mojave, HighSierra) including formatting the hdd while using an usb boot disk; reinstall needs to be finished through safe boot
- Reinstall fresh OS on an external usb hard drive
- SMC Reset (Not sure if it worked)
- NVRAM Reset (Not sure if it worked)
- Using a different apple ID
- Using only a local user account

Laptop has been tested at an apple store, the folks recommend a new logic board. Furthermore, they claim the problem would not occur in case the laptop is connected to an external monitor. I cannot confirm this myself. I can confirmt his now!

The whole story started after the password had been entered several times and the user profile did not load anymore while entering the right password.

---

Update from May 04, 2020:

- **It is really only the MacBook Monitor freezing**. Means, the laptop itself is still working and programs (such as) youtube continuing working, but the monitor is not showing it. Controlling youtube through the keyboard is still function (e.g. increase volume, pause, start). Furthermore, remote control is (e.g. through TeamViewer) working while the monitor of the MacBook is frozen.
- When having an external monitor connected using the HDMI port, none of above mentioned occurs. The macbook monitor as well as the external monitor are function just fine.

---

Update from June 04, 2020:

- Logicboard has been changed
- MBR lost due to logicboard changed. MacOS Catalina has been installed. For this, hdd formatted and OS fresh installed via USB boot stick.
- Installation has been interrupted. MB needed to be strated in safe boot. Pictures showing the error message can be seen below. After the safe boot, MBP was function just fine for almost 2 weeks.

---

Update from June 18, 2020:

- MacBook has since yesterday the same problem.
- Monitor screen is freezing. In addition, it seems the mac is getting hot even tough no tasks are being performed.
- LogicBoard has been changed a couple of weeks ago, so it is unlikely that the problem is being caused from a component related to the logicboard.

---

Update from July 14, 2020:

- Installed Ubuntu 20.04.
- MacBook Pro is running just fine without any issue.
- It seems that the whole problem is iOS related.

---

**MBP Specs:**
[image: 7]

[image: 8]

---

**ERROR MESSAGES:**

Error message from June 04, immediately after replacing the logic board:
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

---

Error Message from June 15, 2020:

> "panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801909167c): Sleep transition timed out
> after 180 seconds while entering darkwake on way to sleep. Suspected
> bundle: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily. Thread 0x74. Failure code::
> 0xb1c0006f 00000031   Backtracing specified thread Backtrace (CPU 0),
> Frame : Return Address 0xffffff8025543900 : 0xffffff8018a458f8
> 0xffffff811b33b9b0 : 0xffffff80189413f1 0xffffff811b33ba20 :
> 0xffffff801893fc2f 0xffffff811b33ba70 : 0xffffff8018a429f9
> 0xffffff811b33bab0 : 0xffffff8018a4225b 0xffffff811b33bae0 :
> 0xffffff7f99d2aced 0xffffff811b33bb10 : 0xffffff7f99d43f65
> 0xffffff811b33bb20 : 0xffffff7f99d2dcb9 0xffffff811b33bbb0 :
> 0xffffff7f99d33549 0xffffff811b33bc50 : 0xffffff8019001b6f
> 0xffffff811b33bcc0 : 0xffffff801901a210 0xffffff811b33bd60 :
> 0xffffff8019002359 0xffffff811b33bdb0 : 0xffffff80190178bb
> 0xffffff811b33be50 : 0xffffff8019013cee 0xffffff811b33bea0 :
> 0xffffff80190117e0 0xffffff811b33bef0 : 0xffffff8019011679
> 0xffffff811b33bf30 : 0xffffff801902cede 0xffffff811b33bf70 :
> 0xffffff801902c4d6 0xffffff811b33bfa0 : 0xffffff80188c513e
> Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
> com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[B1C0006F-E1F5-37D9-9548-5F918E92B422]@0xffffff7f99d22000->0xffffff7f99d72fff
> dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BE052F4D-9B80-3FCD-B36D-BACB7DEE0DF2]@0xffffff7f99331000
> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task   Mac OS
> version: 19F101   Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue
> May 26 20:41:44 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel
> UUID: 54F1A78D-6F41-32BD-BFED-4381F9F6E2EF Kernel slide:
> 0x0000000018600000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff8018800000
> __HIB  text base: 0xffffff8018700000 System model name: MacBookPro11,1 (Mac-189A3D4F975D5FFC) System shutdown begun: NO Panic diags file
> available: YES (0x0)   System uptime in nanoseconds: 6517165226538
> last loaded kext at 6046378979015: |IO!BUSBDFU            7.0.5f6
> (addr 0xffffff7f9c2eb000, size 16384) last unloaded kext at
> 6300792828719: >usb.cdc 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f9c278000, size 28672)
> loaded kexts: @filesystems.smbfs        3.4.3
>
> > AudioAUUC      1.70 @fileutil               20.036.15
> > AGPM 111.4.4
> > !APlatformEnabler         2.7.0d0
> > X86PlatformShim           1.0.0 @filesystems.autofs        3.0
> > !AHDA 283.15
> > !AUpstreamUserClient 3.6.8
> > !AGraphicsDevicePolicy               5.2.4 @AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics      5.2.4
> > !AHV   1 |IOUserEthernet               1.0.1 |IO!BSerialManager        7.0.5f6
> > !ABacklight       180.3
> > pmtelemetry   1
> > !A!IHD5000Graphics     14.0.6 @Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X              7.0.0
> > eficheck             1
> > !AMCCSControl               1.14
> > !ASMCLMU       212
> > !A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking           4.0.0
> > !ACameraInterface        7.6.0
> > !A!IFramebufferAzul     14.0.6
> > !ALPC  3.1
> > !AThunderboltIP             3.1.4
> > !UCardReader 489.120.1
> > !UTCKeyboard 255
> > !UTCButtons    255
> > !AVirtIO             1.0 @filesystems.hfs.kext     522.100.5 @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless          1.0.0d1
> > @BootCache      40 @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
> > @filesystems.apfs            1412.120.2
> > !AAHCIPort       341.0.2 @private.KextAudit         1.0
> > AirPort.BrcmNIC             1400.1.1
> > !ASmartBatteryManager             161.0.0
> > !ARTC  2.0
> > !AACPIButtons 6.1
> > !AHPET               1.8
> > !ASMBIOS         2.1
> > !AACPIEC           6.1
> > !AAPIC                1.7 $!AImage4          1 @nke.applicationfirewall              303 $TMSafetyNet   8
> > @!ASystemPolicy             2.0.0 |EndpointSecurity            1
> > @kext.triggers   1.0
> > DspFuncLib       283.15 @kext.OSvKernDSPLib   529
> > !AGraphicsControl         5.2.4 |IOAVB!F             850.1
> > !ASSE  1.0
> > !ABacklightExpert          1.1.0 @!AGPUWrangler            5.2.4
> > !ASMBus!C       1.0.18d1 |IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F          1.0.0 |IONDRVSupport              576.1
> > X86PlatformPlugin        1.0.0 @!AGraphicsDeviceControl          5.2.4 |IOAccelerator!F2            438.5.4
> > IOPlatformPlugin!F        6.0.0d8
> > !AHDA!C            283.15 |IOGraphics!F    576.1 |IOHDA!F             283.15 @plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3 |IOEthernetAVB!C           1.1.0 |Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport            7.0.5f6
> > |IO!BHost!CUSBTransport            7.0.5f6 |IO!BHost!CTransport
> > 7.0.5f6 |IO!B!F 7.0.5f6 |IO!BPacketLogger          7.0.5f6
> > usb.!UHub        1.2
> > !UMultitouch   264
> > usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice           1.2
> > usb.networking               5.0.0
> > usb.!UHostCompositeDevice     1.2 |IOAudio!F          300.2 @vecLib.kext     1.2.0 |IOSerial!F          11 |IOSurface
> > 269.11 @filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext               1 |IOAHCIBlock!S 316.100.5 |IOAHCI!F            290.0.1
> > !AThunderboltDPInAdapter       6.2.6
> > !AThunderboltDPAdapter!F       6.2.6
> > !AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter              2.5.4
> > !AThunderboltNHI         5.8.6 |IOThunderbolt!F             7.6.1 |IO80211!F         1200.12.2b1
> > mDNSOffloadUserClient              1.0.1b8
> > corecapture     1.0.4 |IOSkywalk!F      1
> > usb.!UXHCIPCI 1.2
> > usb.!UXHCI       1.2 |IOUSB!F             900.4.2
> > !AEFINVRAM    2.1
> > !AEFIRuntime  2.1 |IOSMBus!F        1.1 |IOHID!F              2.0.0 $quarantine        4 $sandbox             300.0 @kext.!AMatch 1.0.0d1
> > DiskImages       493.0.0
> > !AFDEKeyStore                28.30
> > !AEffaceable!S 1.0
> > !AKeyStore       2
> > !UTDM               489.120.1 |IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   422.120.3
> > !ACredentialManager   1.0
> > KernelRelayHost             1
> > !ASEPManager 1.0.1
> > IOSlaveProcessor           1 |IOUSBMass!SDriver       157.121.1 |IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F       422.120.3 |IO!S!F  2.1 |IOUSBHost!F
> > 1.2
> > !UHostMergeProperties              1.2
> > usb.!UCommon              1.0
> > !ABusPower!C 1.0 |CoreAnalytics!F               1
> > !AMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5 @kext.CoreTrust              1 |IOTimeSync!F  840.3 |IONetworking!F              3.4 |IOReport!F
> > 47
> > !AACPIPlatform               6.1
> > !ASMC 3.1.9
> > watchdog          1 |IOPCI!F               2.9 |IOACPI!F            1.4 @kec.pthread    1 @kec.corecrypto              1.0 @kec.Libm          1

Comment: “Finishing the install in Safe Mode” makes no sense since SM only prevents 3rd party apps/kexts from loading.  Install procedure would have no 3rd party anything installed.  Then you say “using only a local account”. are you tying this to Active Directory or something?

Comment: Hi Allan,
The whole thing makes no sense for me - really dont understand it anymore. 
Concerning the installation, after reboot I need to force  into SM in order to finish the installation. Mac isnt rebooting otherwise.
Concerning the local user, I tried that one in order to make sure it is not a problem with the apple ID or any connected 3rd party apps. What do you mean with Active Directory?.

Comment: @Allan: Do you have any further idea?

Comment: Go with the logic board exchange. It could be a GPU issue.

Comment: @Allan Just replaced the logic board. Similar issue appears, monitor screen is freezing during mac os installation. Sometimes the monitor is back operating after a few seconds or mac book is restarting by itself.

Comment: It’s basically a different computer now and it’s doing the same thing with a fresh install?  How exactly are you reinstalling?

Comment: @Allan I have installed MacOS via an USB stick (Mac OS Catalina). Furthermore, I have deleted existing volumes and formatted the ssd using Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and GUID-Partitionstabelle. 
Btw, after replacing the logic board I have received an error message while starting the MacBook. The display showed a "folder symbol" with a "?". My review brought up that this indicates "no existing start volume". Therefore, I re-installed the Mac OS.

Comment: @Allan I literally just booted up using "safe boot" and received an error report. After restarting the Mac in normal mode, I have not experienced the issue any further so far. The Mac is now running without a problem and now loading the recent updates. I will provide an update later today.
The error message looks weird to me. It is concerning a panic (CPU 2 caller...). In addition, the model is being named as "MacBookPro 11,1" even though it is a 13". I took some pictures. May I ask you to have a look at them?

Comment: That “USB Stick” was created with Apple’s `createinstallmedia` utility?  (Just being thorough).  The flashing folder w/ question mark means it cant fine an OS so, reinstall was correct. [MacBookPro11,1](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=MacBookPro11,1) covers a range of 13” MacBook Pro computers, so that’s ok.  If you provide the report, I’m happy to look at it.

Comment: I created the boot stick using the terminal and following command "sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Catalina.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume". Created while being booted in safe mode.
How can I send you the pictures?

Comment: Just post the pictures to the question.

Comment: @Allan Okay, pictures are uploaded.

Comment: Pretty much the only photo needed is the first one as it has the error, its a bit cut off, but I think i can get enough.  The error *userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from com.apple.WindowServer* indicates a GPU issue.  You didn’t say if your MBP had a discrete GPU (NVIDIA) or used the built in Intel Iris.  If you have the discrete GPU, go into System Preferences -> Energy Saver and uncheck “Auto graphics switching.  This will force the Mac to use the GPU.  Then find a 4K video and play it (you might have to loop).  If it crashes, it’s your GPU.

Comment: @Allan The MBP does not have a discrete GPU. I have added two more pictures showing 1) tech specs overview and 2) energy saving options.

Comment: Please just *type* in your specs and energy saving preferences. For instance, by saying you don’t have a GPU it’s already known your machine doesn’t have the ability for “automatic graphics switching.” However, a short sentence reiterating that would suffice.  Tapping to view pictures actually takes the reader away from the question.  Remember, pictures aren’t searchable

Comment: Did you do a clean (wipe the drive and start fresh) install after changing the logic board?

Comment: MBP Specs:
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid2014)
- Processor 2,6GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
- Memory 8GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Graphics Intel Iris 1536 MB

Yes, I wiped off the SSD and even deleted the volumes, and created a new fresh partition.

Comment: Monitor has frozen today and MBK restarted.
Error Message: 
"panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801909167c): Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while entering darkwake on way to sleep. Suspected bundle: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily. Thread 0x74.
Failure code:: 0xb1c0006f 00000031"
I have posted the whole error message from June 15 to the question.

@Allan: Any hint what could the problem?

Comment: @Allen MacBook has since yesterday the same problem. Monitor screen is freezing. In addition, it seems the mac is getting hot even tough no tasks are being performed. LogicBoard has been changed a couple of weeks ago, so it is unlikely that the problem is being caused from a component related to the logicboard. What else could cause this deviation?